# display column names in Oracle using pivot

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to display the `ename` in 4 columns namely `MANAGER` ,`SALESMAN`, `ANALYST`, `CLERK` in `SCOTT` schema in oracle 11g where only the names of ones who are managers get displayed in 1st column, salesmans in 2nd and so on.

So far I have done this:

```
select * 
  from (select job,
               ename 
          from emp) 
 pivot (listagg(ename,',') within group(order by ename) 
   for job in ('MANAGER','CLERK','ANALYST','SALESMAN'))
```

which gives me the desired result but I want in different rows and not multiple values in a single column's value

Anyone can help me display the column names in new columns of PIVOT because it only displays the aggregate functions which typically return a single row where i want multiple rows.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: try to delete listagg function

Comment: @l3rutt and what should I use instead?You see pivot expects an aggregate function at that position.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to summarize it, I would suggest to use decode:

```
select decode(job,'MANAGER',ename) Manager, 
       decode(job,'CLERK',ename) CLERK, 
       decode(job,'CLERK',ename) CLERK,
       decode(job,'SALESMAN',ename) SALESMAN
from emp;
```

Comment: It gives a non-formatted output. I want all columns filled in any row with data. In case other columns have data then the remaining ones should display 'null' which will happen in only last few rows I suppose.

Comment: could you please  update the question with the desired output